# Search for item in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm doing a little test project in ASP.NET MVC. I want to search for specific model item in the view.

**Testproject/Controllers/TestController**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    List<FooModel> testList = new List<FooModel>() { };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(testList);
    }
}
```

**Testproject/Models/FooModel.cs**

```
public class FooModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TestString{ get; set; }
}
```

**Testproject/Views/Test/Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Testproject.Models.FooModel>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    @Model.Find(Id = 3)
</body>
</html>
```

Is there some way to set the type of Id in FooModel to a key type or something so that I can search for it from the IEnumerable-model in the view?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Dictionary.

```
@model IDictionary<int, Testproject.Models.FooModel>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    @Model[3]
</body>
</html>
```